# By mistake I deleted the default .emacs.d directory that comes with emacs25

Tags: emacs

As in the title. I deleted the `.emacs.d` directory by mistake. How can I regenerate it?

Comment: There is no default `.emacs.d` directory.  Emacs will create one if it needs to, but it will happily run without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `emacs` it will generate default `.emacs.d` and `.emacs`

Comment: C-h v user-emacs-directory give ~/.emacs.d/  as its value.